# Grouped means in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I found the following code from a published paper. In this specific case, I'd say that the strategy works well as it's clear and there are relatively few variables. However, the code is "a bit" repetitive, and I wonder if there is a less repetitive way to do it, that would still conform to the `dplyr` style and way of life.

[image]

A test case:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(GR=sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE),
       as.data.frame(replicate(20, rnorm(100))))
names(df)[-1] <- LETTERS[1:20]
```

Now table of grouped means using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(df[,-1], df[1],mean)
```

... and with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(GR) %>% summarize(mean.A=mean(A),
                                  mean.B=mean(B),
                                  mean.C=mean(C),
                                  mean.D=mean(D),
                                  mean.E=mean(E),
                                  # skipped 14 rows
                                  mean.T=mean(T))
```

Is there a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) way of doing this in `dplyr`? I know that all programming tools in R are also available in `dplyr` - so the question is not about HOW to do it .. rather, I'm looking for an idiomatic `dplyr` way of doing this. I've seen similar but much longer examples in real life.

Comment: Yes, you can use `summarise_all(mean)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are multiple columns to `summarise`, use either `summarise_all` (if all the other columns needs to be summarised with a function except the grouping variable)

```
df %>%
   group_by(GR) %>%
   summarise_all(funs(mean = mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

If we need to do this only on selected columns, then try with `summarise_at`

```
df %>%
   group_by(GR) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(A, B, C, D, E), funs(mean = mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Also, check for `summarise_if` when we wanted to apply the function only on certain `type`s of columns

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! The `setNames` part from the other answer is also good as the names may otherwise end up being rather ugly.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(GR) %>% 
  summarise_all(.funs = mean) %>% 
  setNames(paste("mean", colnames(.), sep = "."))
```